# ListItem not highlighted even though selected is true

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, listbox

I am creating a list of months for a list box.  The controller captures the selected months and stores them in session for if the user navigates away from the page then returns.

Here is the controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(int[] Months)
{
    if (Session["Months"] == null || Months!= null)
            Session["Months"] = Months;
        else if (Months== null)
            Months= Session["Months"] as int[];

    IList<SelectListItem> MonthsList = utility.GetMonths().OrderBy(r => r.Name)
        .Select(r => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = r.Name,
            Value = r.Id.ToString(),
            Selected = Months == null ? false : Months.Contains(r.Id)
        }).ToList();

    var model = new DataModel
    {
        SelectList = MonthsList,
        Data = GetDataByMonths(Months)
    };
    return (model);
}
```

Here is the view:

```
@Html.ListBox("Months", Model.SelectList)
```

When the user selects items from the ListBox they are highlighted even after the form has been submitted.  However when the user navigates away then returns the SelectListItems are correctly labeled as Selected = true but the DOM does not show this.

Any ideas on why this only doesnt work when session is used?

EDIT:

Tried:

```
@Html.ListBox("Months", new MultiSelectList(Model.Months, "Value", "Text", Model.SelectedMonths), new { size = 8 })
```

While debugging, the variables show the correct values, they are just not correctly highlighted in the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating the list box in html rather than using the `@html.listbox()`

```
<select name="Months" id="Months" multiple="multiple" size="8">
    @foreach (var a in Model.Months)
    {
        <option value="@a.Value" @(a.Selected.ToString() == "True" ? "selected='selected'" : "")>@a.Text</option>
    }
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the `SelectList` type or `MultiSelectList` rather than an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`? I don't know of any other way to tell the ListBox which property is the `value` and which is the `text`.

i.e.

```
MultiSelectList list = new MultiSelectList(monthsList, "Value", "Text");
```

and return the `list` object?

Comment: thanks for the response, tried this and still getting the same issue.